# Search string for substring using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm new to c++. How do I search a string to find a certain part of that string?

For example if I searched the user input string of 150lbs and tried looking for "lbs" I'd return a boolean that's true?

I tried using regex but I'm stuck

Comment: stuck on what? would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: First result in Google returns a pretty decent tutorial on what you are asking (not for `lbs` in particular but close).Writing "tried using regex but i'm stuck" doesn't provide any useful information. What have you tried exactly? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real quick answer.

```
bool isLbs(string s){
    return (s.find("lbs") != string::npos);
}
```

This will work. But how you might ask.

First of all I would suggest reading [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) first.

Now it really is very simple. The class std::String in C++ has a function called find which can be used to check if a string exists inside a string. The type that it returns is an unsigned integral type so to convert that to a bool you will need to check if str.find("searchWord") != string::npos. Because if it does equal to string::npos then it doesn't exist in the string.

As I said feel free to read the more in depth documentation over at cplusplus.com.

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

P.S The function above also returns true if you pass "3213lbs2313" or "lbs1234124". So it doesn't care where lbs is as long as it is inside of the string. If you would like to only check if it is at the end then you can just check `if (s.substr(s.size()-3) == "lbs")` which calls another function of the std::String class that returns the last 3 characters of your string and checks if they are equal to "lbs".